# Emacs style shortcuts not working in Terminal.app on Montery

Tags: macos, terminal, shortcut, zsh

When typing commands in Terminal I expect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to take me to the beginning of the line and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to the end of the line, for some reason though this seems to have stopped working at some point (I'm pretty sure it did in the past). Other [command line shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/terminal/trmlshtcts/mac) also do not work, although <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> does.

Instead the key sequence is inserted literally with a white highlight. Pressing backspace removes the `^A` character pairs with a single press.

[image: Screenshot of a Terminal window with Ctrl characters shown]

I'm using ZSH on an M1 (2020) Mac Mini running Monterey 12.6 (21G115) and my command line tools are up to date.

My prompt looks like this:

```
# Zsh prompt
prompt='%F{green}%2~ %#%f '
export prompt
```

I've tried toggling **Use Option As Meta Key** in Terminal preferences without joy. I also have some modifications to `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` but I tried removing them and it also didn't help.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Giles for helping me find a solution. Turns out I had the following in my `~/.zshenv`, putting me in vi mode.

```
EDITOR="nvim"
export EDITOR
```

I was able fix my issue by removing those lines, or by adding `bindkey -e` below.

Comment: Are you using oh-my-zsh? https://superuser.com/questions/523564/emacs-keybindings-in-zsh-not-working-ctrl-a-ctrl-e#523973

Comment: There's an inconsistency in your question: does Ctrl+K work? (I guess it doesn't, and you are indeed in vi mode.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like symptoms of zsh using vi-like bindings when you expect emacs-like bindings. With vi-like bindings, by default, most control characters insert themselves, but <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> erases the line (however, <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> inserts itself, like <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd>).

With vi-like bindings, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> switches to vi command mode, where characters don't insert themselves anymore but instead run vi commands. Press `i` or `a` to go back to insert mode.

Zsh uses vi-like bindings if the `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` environment variable designates vi. You can force emacs-like bindings instead by putting the following line in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
bindkey -e
```